# ffmpeg stream desktop instead -i /dev/video0

Tags: html, ffmpeg, stream

How can I set ffmpeg to stream desktop instead web cam -i /dev/video0
here is example command that I used

```
$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8080/feed.ffm
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux use [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vf format=yuv420p http://localhost:8080/feed.ffm
```

Comment: tnx @0day and you llogan to